# Java Thread Fork In An Existing Old Method Of Code

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have a old code like the below. At some point I want this code to run in two threads. But **my modification right to the existing code is restricted**. Because business logic in the code is very complex. And so I dont want to divide the method in to two or more. Below is a sample code?

```
public void task1(){
      logger.debug(thisThreadName+"Issue 1");
      logger.debug(thisThreadName+"Issue 2");
      logger.debug(thisThreadName+"Validate 1");
      logger.debug(thisThreadName+"Issue 3");
      logger.debug(thisThreadName+"Validate 2");
}
```

and what I want to is:

```
    1) Domain Thread shoud write Issue1, Issue2
    2) The Domain Thread should create a new one 
    3) The Domain Thread should start to wait. 
    4) The New thread should run till the end of method 
    5) The New Thread should write Validate 1, Issu3, Validate 2
    6) The New Thread should set controlVariable( true or false)
    7) The New Thread should be finish and destroyed.
    8) The Domain Thread should control controlVariable. If it is true. It should jump to the end of method. If it is false. It should rewrite Issue1 and Issue2                                  

    Sample Output Is:
    DomainThread Issue 1 
    DomainThread Issue 2
    NewThread    Validate 1
    NewThread    Issue 3
    NewThread    Validate 2
```

**Is there a solution for this requirement?**

**BY THE WAY: I may not change method signature and  method implementation block. I may just add extra lines of codes in the method.**

**What I want to achieve is: Main thread should know if it be validated for Validation1 and Validation2, before it runs validations.**

Comment: That's not a question.Also, the order you say you want things to happen shows you don't need another thread.  If main thread just waits for new thread to do something why not do the something on the main thread?

Comment: Thank you @JJF.  
This is about validation. New thread makes validations. Issue3 and Issue5 is about validation. Issue4 is a change Value operation. If these validations succeeds main thread will continue to run. Else it will do something else. It is about rollback. Main thread should know if it will be validated or not validated before it runs Issue4.